# Continuity of $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ at $x = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, continuity, power-series

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, for $x \in (1, 1]$. I know that $f(x) = \arctan x$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$: this is because
$$ \arctan x  = \int \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\,dx = \int \left( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^{2n}\right)\,dx = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + C,$$
with $C = \arctan 0 = 0$, and this series (resulting from integration) has the same radius of convergence that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, namely $R = 1$. Now, it is widely known that $f(1) = \arctan 1$ (Gregory series). Why? I know that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ converges (by Leibniz test), but I cannot see why it must converge to $\arctan 1$: the theorem of integration of power series says nothing about the endpoints of the interval of convergence. If I could prove that $f$ is left continuous at $1$, then the result would follows: $f(1) = \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \arctan x = \arctan 1$. Is this really what is missing? If yes, then how to prove that $f$ is continuous at $1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is due to [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem): if a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then, for each $x\in(-1,1)$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges and$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$So,\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\arctan(x)\\&=\arctan(1)\\&=\frac\pi4.\end{align}